# JavaScript: check if html p tag is empty

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following in my project:

```js
function check() {
  var empt = document.getElementById('xyz1').value;

  if (empt == "") {
    alert("Please input a Value");
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="test.html" role="button" name="weiter" id="weiter" onclick="check();">Go</a>
<p id="xyz1"></p>
```

Something I am doing wrong. I always get to the page test.html. The check is not working. Is it even possible, to check if a p tag is empty?
Goal is, if there is nothing in the p tag to get an alert and if there is a string or number getting to the linked page test.html
I would like to work in pure JavaScript (no jQuery).

Comment: `p` doesn't have a `value` property. Use `textContent` or `innerText` to check if the element contains any text, to check if it contains any child HTML then `innerHTML` will suffice.

Comment: use innerHTML function

Comment: @madhur `innerHTML` isn’t a function.

Comment: I mean innerHTML property on element

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
  function check() {
   event.preventDefault();
    var empt = document.getElementById('xyz1').innerHTML;
    if (empt == null || empt == "")
    {
      alert("Please input a Value");
      return false;
    }
    else 
    {
     return true; 
    }
  }
```

```html
<a href="test.html" role="button" name="weiter" id="weiter" onclick="check();">Go</a>
<p id="xyz1"></p>
```

Function must be event prevent default otherwise run href after on click event.

**Another Method**

```
onclick="return check()"
```

```js
  function check() { 
    var empt = document.getElementById('xyz1').innerHTML;
    if (empt == null || empt == "")
    {
      alert("Please input a Value");
      return false;
    }
    else 
    {
     return true; 
    }
  }
```

```html
<a href="test.html" role="button" name="weiter" id="weiter" onclick="return check();">Go</a>
<p id="xyz1"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you, works as excepted. "event.preventDefault()" is new for me...

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` won’t work, because `event` isn’t defined. Instead, using `addEventListener` and an event handler with an `event` argument will work.

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` work because `onclick=""` is a event and javascript 
perceives it. As proof, you can try this;`console.log(event)` *output:*  [link](http://prntscr.com/hup24j) @Xufox

Comment: @HüseyinASLIM No, it won’t work. `onclick=""` is not an event, it’s an attribute. `event` isn’t defined anywhere. Neither as a global variable nor as a parameter. Some browsers may support a _non-standard_ `window.event`, but that doesn’t mean that it “works”.

Comment: @Xufox This attr is related to onclick event. Console logs and tests show that the event is defined and works, for example.
If you do not accept all of these, you can present your own solution.
I also suggested 2 methods.Thanks! Good day.

Answer (score 3):

It's innerHTML instead of value.  Also, check for null.

```js
function check() {

  var empt = document.getElementById('xyz1').innerHTML;
  if (empt == null || empt == "")
  {
  alert("Please input a Value");
  return false;
  }
  else 
  {
  return true; 
  }
  }
```

```html
<a href="test.html" role="button" name="weiter" id="weiter" onclick="check();">Go</a>
<p id="xyz1"></p>
```

Comment: Why should TO test for `null`?

Comment: Not sure if you need null test actually...but it's innerHTML

Comment: Thanks John it seems it will really check now if the tag is empty or not. Problem now is if I confirm my alert I will be linked directly to the test.html page which is not what I need. The link should just work if the p tag is not empty.

Comment: return check(); That's what you need...instead of just check() as the onclick

Comment: `.innerHTML` never evaluates to `null`. Just check for `""`, or `.trim()` it first, _then_ check for `""`.